# Replace leading zeroes does not work without making explicit the Ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

- I am using the SQL Server 2012.

I was updating a column named *PostNumber* in a table to put leading zeroes. Its data type is nvarchar(50). It should be 6 digits always. If not six, it should be padded with leading zeroes. I have tried with the following T-SQL:

```
update table1
set PostNumber=RIGHT('000000'+ISNULL(PostNumber,''),6)
```

The initial table1 is:

```
   Id   PostNumber
    1       234
    2      24545
    3     435434
```

What we need to do:

```
    Id   PostNumber

    1      000234
    2      024545
    3      435434
```

Very strangely it does not work with the former T-SQL! Unless we explicitly set the Id..

```
update table1
set PostNumber=RIGHT('000000'+ISNULL(PostNumber,''),6)
where Id between 1 and 3
```

The last T-SQL works, but I do not know **why the former T-SQL does not work** ! The table remains the same without putting any zeroes at all. Could you provide a possible cause? Thanks. 
I really need a bulk update without making explicit the Ids.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: it is nvarchar(50)

Comment: Perhaps auto-commit is off and you need to commit the transaction.

Comment: Well SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS is unchecked...

Comment: Does it work with WHERE Id IS NOT NULL?

Comment: _The initial table1 is_... I can see leading spaces (unless it is a typo) which explains what is going on.

Comment: yes, it worked OTTA .

Comment: Side note: If it's a post *number* that should always have exactly 6 digits, it should be `char(6)` and not `nvarchar(50)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your actual issue

If your column `PostNumber` is of a numeric type, the value `123` will be the same as the value `000123`. Leading zeros are a matter of string types or - in most cases something you need only in your presentation layer.

### UPDATE Did not read carefully enough...

In a comment you stated, that the column is a `nvarchar(50)`

It might be, that there are blanks around your values, try this:

```
set PostNumber=RIGHT('000000'+ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(PostNumber)),''),6)
```

Check with

```
SELECT PostNumber,LEN(PostNumber),DATALENGTH(PostNumber) FROM ...
```

### padding approaches

There are several approaches, I prefer the one with `REPLACE` on `STR`

```
DECLARE @number INT=34;
SELECT REPLACE(STR(@number,6),' ','0')
```

The problem with the very usual approach with `RIGHT` is the fact, that it will return bad result in cases were the number exceeds the number of digits.

```
DECLARE @number6 INT=123456;
SELECT REPLACE(STR(@number6,6),' ','0')
      ,RIGHT('000000'+ISNULL(@number6,''),6);

DECLARE @number7 INT=1234567;
SELECT REPLACE(STR(@number7,6),' ','0')
      ,RIGHT('000000'+ISNULL(@number7,''),6);
```

To be honest: My favorite approach has a weakness with negativ numbers:

```
DECLARE @numberMinus INT=-15;
SELECT REPLACE(STR(@numberMinus,6),' ','0')
      ,RIGHT('000000'+ISNULL(@numberMinus,''),6);
```

Starting with SQL-Server 2012 there is `FORMAT()`

```
SELECT FORMAT(@number,'000000')
```

Not the best perfomer, but works nicely.

Comment: Ah... just tell him to use INT datatype and format the data for display.

Comment: Datalength gives 12 and LEN gives 6... (now for all rows), Your T-SQL PostNumber=RIGHT('000000'+ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(PostNumber)),''),6) did the trick . But why these spaces can affect the difference between the two T-SQL I have written? Could you explain, please?

Comment: @graphene If there is a value like (blanks as dots for visibility) `.......123` Your approach would create `000000.......123` and take 6 from the right. You see what I mean?

Comment: Very thorough answer, @Shnugo, but I'm still trying to sort how the OP's second query worked. I can't reproduce that. Any thoughts?

Comment: @EricBrandt I assume there had been a padding with blanks done earlier and not all values were padded